# Access a specific version of text in Vue I18n

Tags: vue.js, localization

I wanted to access a specific version of a text in my localized strings for example.

```js
en : {
  title: "Title from en" 
},
ja: {
  title: "Title from Ja"
}
```

if the selected locale is **ja**

I want to access **title** from the english(**en**) locale.

something like this `$t("title", "en")`.

Comment: It should be as you mentioned https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#t

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Comment: this does not work. I am using nuxt. it just says cannot translate the value of keypath keypath

Comment: How are you initializing VueI18n?